# Can most of the data structures be implemented using vectors?

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector

I used C++ vectors to implement stacks, queue, heaps, priority queue and directed weighted graphs. In the books and references, I have seen big classes for these data structures, all of which can be implemented in short using vectors. (May be there is more flexibility in using pointers)

Can we also implement even advanced data structures using vectors ?
If yes, why do C++ books still explain concepts with the long classes using pointers ?

Is it to keep in mind the lower level idea, if it is more vivid that way or it makes students equipped with such usage of pointers ?

Comment: If you're only interested in answers in the context of C++ please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: If a datastructure requires an array object, then use a vector. If it doesn't, then don't. For example, `map`s cannot use a vector and be standards compliant.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: I'd like to see a reference for that. `std::map` requires an allocator for its memory management, and I don't see why a `vector` couldn't serve as one.

Comment: I don't think implementing an allocator based on `vector` is a "valid" approach in the sense of the question, as it's built around the claim that using a `vector` would lead to simpler code (whereas the code is just as complex using an allocator, plus the allocator code!). Implementing std containers in terms of `vector` otherwise is not possible, for example `stack` is `O(1)` for pushing/popping at the front whereas `vector` is not. Thus, if you "disguise" a `vector` as a `stack`, it simply doesn't do what it should do.

Comment: Vectors are for containing objects of the same type.  For example, I can't use a vector to contain: string name, int age, float rate.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's not a data structure in the sense of this question (a collection if you will).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I can create a vector of tuples which can have different datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that many data structures can be implemented on top of a vector (array, for the sake of this answer), essentially all of them can, since every computation task can be implemented to run on a turing-machine which has a far more basic data access capability (or, in the real world, you may say that any program you implement with pointers eventually runs on a CPU with a simply array-like virtual memory space, so you could just call that a huge array). However, it's not always clever. Two main reasons :

1. performance / time complexity - a vector simply can't provide all basic operations that in O(1). There's a solution for fast initialization, but try to randomly insert values into a large vector and see how bad you perform - that's because you have to move all the elements by one place over and over. A list could do that in a single operation. Of course other structures have their own performance shortcomings, but that's the beauty of designing complicated data structures with these basic building blocks.
2. structural complexity - you can think of a list along the same line of a vector as an ordered container, and perhaps extend this into multidimensional matrices that can be implemented on top of them since they still retain some basic ordering, but there are more complicated structures. Take for e.g. a tree, a simple full binary tree one can be implemented with a vector very easily since the parent-child relations can be easily converted to index arithmetics, but what if the tree isn't full and has varying number of children per node? Now, you may say it can still be done (any graph can be implemented with vectors either through adjacency matrix or adjacency list for e.g.), but there's almost no sense in doing so when you can have a much simpler implementation using pointer links. Just think of doing an AVL roll with an array. :shudder:

Mind you that the second argument may very well boil down to performance ("hey, it's an awkward approach but I still managed to use a vector!"), but it's more than that - it would complicate your code, clutter your data structure design, and could make it far more prone to bugs.

Now, here comes the "but" - even though there's much sense in using all the possible tools the language provides you, it's very widely accepted to use vector-based structures for performance critical tasks. See almost all scientific CPU benchmarks, most of them ultimately rely on vectors (uncited, but I can elaborate further if anyone is interested. Suffice to say that even the well-known **graph**500 does that).

The reason is not that it's best programming practice, but that it's more suited with CPU internal structure and gets more "juice" out of the HW. That's due to spatial locality - CPUs are very fond of that as it allows the memory unit to parallelize accesses (in an array you always know where's the next element, in a list you have to wait until the current one is fetched), and also issue stream/stride prefetches that reduce latency of future requests. 
I can't say this is always a good practice, when you run through a graph the accesses are still pretty irregular even if you use an array implementation, but it's still a very common practice.

To summarize, taking the question literally - most of them can, of sorts (for a given definition of "most", ok?), but if the intention was "why teach pointers", I believe you can see that in order to understand your limits and what you can and should use - you need to know a great deal more than just arrays and even pointers. A good programmer should know a bit about everything - OS design, CPU design, etc. You can't do anything decent unless you really understand the fabric you're running on, and that unfortunately (or not) includes lots of pointers

Comment: It's actually fairly trivial to implement linked lists, trees, and other linked data structures atop of a vector. Just use the vector as your RAM and indices as pointers. Sure, you have to perform your own allocation and de-allocation, but a simple pool is easy to implement, performs well, and uses no extra space. The iterator invalidation problem mentioned elsewhere only exists because standard allocators use "real" pointers instead of indices into the vector, which is what one's own implementation can and should do.

Comment: Right, I noted that above, but that's basically a list in almost every aspect. You'll have to use some "next_index" field to get the O(1) insertion, and would therefor "suffer" from the fragmentation just like with a proper list. It still boils down to a contiguous array approach vs "linked" data structure one, in whatever way any of them may be implemented

Comment: I'm not sure whether you misunderstood what I described, whether I misunderstood your objection, or whether you're misusing the term "fragmentation". See http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/02/12/alternatives-to-malloc-and-new/ (the last one) for a detailed explanation of the scheme I'm referring to. If you're saying that it won't be as cache friendly as access to consecutive memory addresses, that's right but it's not exactly surprising. *Any* random access, whether in the course of emulating another data structure or not, has the same "problem".

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks interesting. And I was referring exactly to the performance of random access vs consecutive structures. As I was saying - if not for performance you can implement anything in arrays of course, as with the RAM example, but in the real world you' want something the performs better. By the way, my interest in that comes from studying ways to optimize linked data structures through HW prefetching, under the assumption that they're more "natural" in program and algorithmic contexts, but are often thrown away due to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a kind of [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) using an `std::vector` as the backing store. If you do that, all the standard data structures from elementary computer science can be implemented on top of vectors. It will hardly free you from using pointers, though: vectors are really just chunks of memory with a few useful additional operations, most notably the ability to expand.

More to the point: if you don't understand pointers, you won't understand how to do use `vector` for advanced data structures either. `vector` is a useful abstraction, but it follows the C++ rule that "you don't get what you don't pay for", so it's also a very "thin" abstraction, and you *do* pay for the cost of abstraction in terms of the amount of code you have to write.

(Jonathan Wakely points out, in the comments, that you won't get the exact guarantees that the C++ standard library requires of allocators data structures when you implement them on top of `vector`. Put in principle, vectors are just a way of handling blocks of memory.)

Comment: I don't think "a red-black tree using an allocator that uses vector internally" counts as implementing a red-black tree using vector. You still need to implement the red-black tree logic, which is the complicated part that's specific to a red-black tree, and that can't use a vector.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: if needed, a red-black tree can be implemented more directly using a `vector`; I've implemented tree structures as arrays to prevent memory fragmentation.

Comment: And how do you provide both the iterator invalidation guarantees and algorithmic complexity guarantees that `std::map` has?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: the complexity guarantees are in terms of the number of calls to the comparison function, which will be preserved exactly. But the iterator guarantees are a good point, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I know they are, my point is you can't have _both_ with an array. You can either have O(log n) lookup or you can have stable iterators, not both.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I amended the answer, a check is appreciated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37793/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-larsmans)

Answer (score -1):

If you are learning C++ you need to be familiar with pointers and how to use them even if there are more higher level concepts that does that job for you.
Yes, it is possible to implement most data structures with vectors or lists and if you just started learning programming it's probably a good idea that you'll know how to write these data structures yourself.

With that being said, production code should always use the standard library unless there is a good reason not to do so.